# Derived Class Constructor Returning Null

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, unity-game-engine, constructor

I am creating a chess game, in my code I am generating objects to represent the pieces.

These are all of type `Pawn`, `Rook`, `King` etc and are derived from the `Piece` class.

However, when I attempt to create a new `Pawn` as such:

```
return new Pawn(location, gameObj);
```

Despite the values of `location` and `gameObj` being valid, the returned value is null.

The (unfinished) `Piece` and `Pawn` classes are defined as such:

```
public class Piece : MonoBehaviour
{
protected Coord location;
protected bool isWhite;
protected bool specialUsed = false;

void displayMarkers(List<Coord> targets)
{

}

public void moveTo()
{

}

public void resetColour()
{

}

public virtual void displayTargets()
{

}
}
```

and:

```
public class Pawn : Piece
{
public Pawn(Coord loc, GameObject gameObj)
{
    location = loc;
    if (loc.y < 4) { isWhite = true; } else { isWhite = false; }     
}

public override void displayTargets()
{

}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has me completely stumped. Thanks!

Comment: Show the code where you use the constructor. because a constructor cant return null

Comment: I have, `return new Pawn(location, gameObj);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **Unity**,

In Unity you cannot instantiate a `MonoBehaviour` using `new Pawn()`, you must do that through `AddComponent<T>` method.

As a result, parameterized constructors are useless.

**Example:**

```
var pawn = gameObject.AddComponent<Pawn();
pawn.isWhite = true;
```

See the documentation for more information:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html

Comment: Wow... All I had to do was remove `:MonoBehaviour` Thanks :D